# Can you always treat variables as constants in partial derivatives/integrals?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Ok so imagine you are given an expression: $xy : x=y$, & you need to take the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ *but you don't simplify* (i.e. substitute x=y) --> $d/dx(xy)=y$.

Now you've gotten a different answer than you would have gotten had you simplified/substituted. But in math you should only be able to get 1 correct answer regardless of simplification. So why does standard partial derivative procedure in this trivial example yield 2 seemingly 'correct' answers?

P.S. Ditto question for partial integrals & cases where $x=y + \epsilon: \epsilon\approx 0$.

Comment: The premise behind a partial derivative is that the various unknowns can move independently.

Comment: This isn't part of the question but I have always felt it helpful to use subscript notation for partial derivatives, e.g. $f_1$ and $f_2$ for the partial derivatives of a two-variable function with respect to its first and second variables. It's a thought. $x$ and $y$ tend to be very overloaded in terms of what they represent (and do not themselves notationally capture what might be being held constant).

Comment: "But then all of a sudden you find out new information which is that =," Why? Where is this from?

Comment: @mrsamy Say this is a statistical context. Variables represent real values, if you have a really small sample and in that sample x=y then you won't necessarily know that it generalizes. But later you could take a VERY LARGE sample and find out that it is likely that $x\approx y$.

Comment: It is unclear what your context is. Whenever one wants to talk about partial derivatives, one needs a *function* first. What is your function?

Comment: my function would be: f(x,y)=xy

Comment: Okay. Then what is your reasoning to get $x=y$? There is no statistics whatsoever here: this is a deterministic function. // In the context of statistics, one usually needs the concept of *random variables*, which is a totally different story. If one wants to discuss/phrase a question in statistics, one must do it properly.

Comment: This is what I was sort of getting at in the comment above. You don't "learn that $x=y$" as much as you are probably considering a new and different function of one variable, $t \mapsto f(t,t)$. Putting $x$ in that second coordinate is just a recipe for confusion. To me. Although many can master it.

Comment: @mrsamy Ok fine then lets just say that x=y but I decided not to substitute because in math there should be only 1 possible correct answer anyhow & therefore simplification, although a good idea isn't 'necessary'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) with respect to $x$ of $f(x,y) = xy$ is defined to be the result you get by holding $y$ constant and differentiating with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xy) = y.$$  If you are looking for the total rate of change of $f(x,y) = xy$ with respect to $x$, with the additional information that $y = x$, then you are really looking for the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), and will need to use the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y) = \frac{d}{dx}(xy) = y + x\frac{dy}{dx} = y + x = x + x = 2x,$$ or alternatively by substituting $y = x$ in the expression, you have $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,x) = \frac{d}{dx}x^2 = 2x.$$  It all depends on whether you are in fact looking for the partial derivative or the total derivative.

Comment: So then what use is the partial derivative?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are independent, which is frequently the case, it gives the rate of change of the function with respect to one of the variables.  Note that if $x$ and $y$ are independent, then $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ and so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{df}{dx}$.

Comment: Gotcha that's what I was looking for. Until now I was under the impression that partial derivatives were completely unqualified & rigorously represented rate of change r.t.w. some variable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=xy$. Also consider the function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with $g(x)=(x,x)$. You can then define the composition $h=f\circ g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
$$
h(x)=f(g(x))=f(x,x)=x^2
$$

While understandable, it is confusing to write $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,x)$. What you actually have is the composition of two functions.

The derivative of the function $h$ is $h'(x)=2x$.

On the other hand, the partial derivative with respect to $x$ for $f$ is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=y.
$$